# How to decrease space between CSS grid elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to close or at least decrease the distance between these three elements ( distance is shown in red between each element and the other ) `h4`, `h1` and `p`. I tried the CSS grid
`row-gap:` but it didn't seem to be working and I don't think the problem is in the gaps.
Can anyone tell me how to make these three elements closer to each other.
**Ps : the part of css that I'm working on is the one for desktops, withing the media queries.**

[image]

**Link to my whole source code in Github :** https://github.com/IssamAth/Waitlist-page

```css
/* MEDIA QUERIES ================ ( For desktops ) ================ */

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'one four' 'two four' 'three .';
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .image {
    display: inline-block;
    grid-area: four;
  }
  .image img {
    width: 25rem;
    height: 28rem;
  }
  h1 {
    /* margin-bottom: 8rem; */
    padding: 2rem 10rem 1rem 0rem;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    text-align: start;
    grid-area: two;
    /* font-size: 3.1rem; */
  }
  p {
    text-align: start;
    grid-area: three;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    padding-right: 20rem;
    /* font-size: 0.99em; */
  }
  h4 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    text-align: start;
    height: 3.2rem;
    width: 34rem;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem 0.6rem 1rem;
    grid-area: one;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <h4>We are now allowing early-access for users. <a class="learn">Learn more.</a></h4>
  <h1>Build a highly engaged community with no effort.</h1>
  <p>Commune offers the tools you need to build a highly engaged community with little to no effort. Simply setup your Commune workspace, and manage everything from members to content from one central dashboard.</p>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="illustration" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The problem is with the margin of the header element, just try to remove or decrease the margin of the middle element.

Comment: @Lollergalad U mean the ```h1``` ? I don't think so because its margin is set to zero.

Comment: I can see the `h4` is using zero margin, but `h1` is not, please check it again

Comment: @Lollergalad that is commented and is not part of the actual executed code

Comment: @Lollergalad h1 does not have a margin too those lines are only comments

Comment: @SamRad The browser adds margin by default to `h*` elements, so they do have margin - since you aren't removing it. But that's not the problem. The problem is that your image will affect spacing - since the `h4` and `h1` are in grid areas that will equal the height of the image track (four) - which is dictating the grid track height for one and two. If you want that space to change, you may need to change your markup to combine the `h4/h1` into the same grid area. Irrelevant to the question - do not use h4 before h1. That creates accessibility issues.

Comment: @disinfor oh I didn't know that I can combine two elements into the same grid area. I'm kinda new to everything so big thanks. Also, I appreciate the last piece of advice about accessibility, thanks, man!

Comment: @SamRad you can't assign two elements to the same grid area, you'll have to wrap them in an element (`<div>`) or something and then assign that to the grid area. No problem on accessibility! Often `h4` tags are used as pre-titles and that is a huge issue for screen readers.

Comment: @disinfor Yeah, it is a pre-title, hence why I put it before h1. But I totally forgot that it would mess up the accessibility.  Wrapping em both inside a div is a great idea still ! thanks man

Comment: is it ok to use display flex instead of grid? @SamRad

Comment: @Mad7Dragon Yup, I was thinking about it lol. If I can go back in time, I would rather use flexbox in this case instead of CSS-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex is really good if you learn how to manage HTML structure.

here I change all displays to flex, so you don't need to worry about grid aria or margin issues. it's all under control now.

read the comments for all the info.

```css
/* MEDIA QUERIES ================ ( For desktops ) ================ */

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  * {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* flex-direction: column; */ /* uncomment this to change flex direction to column for mobile view  */
  }

  .left :nth-child(n) {
    margin: 0px 0; /* control margin or padding for all left side elements here */
  }

  .image {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* comment this for mobile view if you don't want the image in the center*/
   align-items: center;
  }
  .image img {
    
    width: 25rem;
    height: 28rem;
  }
  h1 {
    /* margin-bottom: 8rem; */
    padding: 2rem 10rem 1rem 0rem;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    text-align: start;
    
    /* font-size: 3.1rem; */
  }
  p {
    text-align: start;
    
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    padding-right: 20rem;
    /* font-size: 0.99em; */
  }
  h4 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    text-align: start;
    height: 3.2rem;
    width: 34rem;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem 0.6rem 1rem;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
<!-- added one container for left elements -->
  <div class="left"> 
    <h4>We are now allowing early-access for users. <a class="learn">Learn more.</a></h4>
    <h1>Build a highly engaged community with no effort.</h1>
    <p>Commune offers the tools you need to build a highly engaged community with little to no effort. Simply setup your Commune workspace, and manage everything from members to content from one central dashboard.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="illustration" />
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to add grid-template-rows because by default the rows take 1fr size

```css
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'one four' 'two four' 'three .';
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, max-content);
    //or
   grid-template-rows: max-content max-content max-content;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
```